# In shell how do I get stdout & stderr combined in output order and stderr separate too?

Tags: shell, logging, stdout, stderr

For the reason of build logging I want to have a shell script
combining stderr and stdout of a command but also saving stderr only separately so I can show stderr prominently in the beginning. But also have them combined to probably further analyze including the stdout messages if necessary.

Tried a lot around with tee and file descriptors but I do not get this
stuff to work.

I already found that for zsh this should be working `cmd &> all.txt and 2> out.txt` but does unfortunately not on sh.

I also managed to have them together in one file once but, it was not in order, I got all errors followed by the stdout or other way round.

if you try something it should be **sh**.

That is my test script:

```
>&2 echo "error0"
echo "out0"
>&2 echo "error1"
echo "out1"
>&2 echo "error2"
echo "out2"
```

Outputs should be:

```
error0
out0
error1
out1
error2
out2
```

and:

```
error0
error1
error2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
mkfifo logpipe errpipe
tee -a errlog >logpipe <errpipe&
cat logpipe >log&
{ echo foo; echo bar >&2; } >logpipe 2>errpipe
rm logpipe errpipe
```

Best results I could get in `dash` so far (see the buffering discussion in the comments):

```
stdbuf -e0 -o0 test.sh 2>&1 >>log | tee -a log >errlog
```

With `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 10`; do
  echo "error$i" >&2
  echo "out$i"
done
```

I get results like:

```
$ cat log
out1
out2
error1
out3
error2
error3
out4
error4
out5
error5
out6
error6
out7
error7
out8
error8
out9
error9
out10
error10
$ cat errlog
error1
error2
error3
error4
error5
error6
error7
error8
error9
error10
```

Sometimes it's better, sometimes it's worse.

Comment: Add my outputs from the test script instead of the {}, what I get for the log is:

out0
out1
out2
error0
error1
error2

(I replaced it with sh test.sh where test.sh is my test script from above)

Comment: @Cyborg-X1: That's probably a buffering problem. Try switching to line buffering using e.g. `unbuffer` or `stdbuf`.

Comment: Could you explain that further, I tried with `stdbuf -e 0 -o 0 sh test.sh` now I get `out0 error0 out1 out2 error1 error2`, (better extend your solution above, also better for others dropping by)

Comment: @Cyborg-X1: Maybe there's some other kind of buffering or latency going on. I'm not sure. I'm getting good results on my machine using `unbuffer`.

Comment: Where do you put unbuffer here? I tried the line before the last one, I tried calling the whole script with your solution. But where do you put it? One try the log is correct, but err is empty. On the other same result as before. Btw. working on your machine is nice but not a solution for my machine and not really stable when using different docker containers with different systems. But thanks for your help already. Did not know about unbuffer or stdbuf before.

Comment: @Cyborg-X1: I'm putting it where you put it — otherwise I'd have said something. But you're right: I missed the empty errlog file with `unbuffer`. When using unbuffer, the processes don't seem to quit as they should. For the time being, I'm afraid the `stdbuf` solution is the best I got to offer. (Another clue I found is that `tee` seems to override `stdbufs` changes. I'll look into it tomorrow.) In general, the whole buffering business can get pretty tricky. Maybe someone else will come up with a better solution alltogether.)

Comment: Yeah it seems quite tricky, I found multiple unfinished solutions which did not work. Some filebuffer magic as well, nothing worked there. Really wonder why there are not more answers in the net for such a use-case. Is it so "fancy" to get those two things? Well, probably yes as it seems... or others just gave up.

Comment: @Cyborg-X1: In `dash`, this one works best for me: `stdbuf -e0 -o0 test.sh 2>&1 >>log | tee -a log >errlog`. It's still not perfect, though.

Comment: Well, if I'd wanted to install a dash, bash, zsh shell in each container, I would not have asked this question and went with zsh. The problem is I want it to work in sh because it is already there in every container, best with none of unbuffer or stdbuf, as for example in alpine there is no stdbuf or unbuffer installed by default. Even on ubuntu containers there is no unbuffer.

Comment: @Cyborg-X1: `dash` is just one of the most used options for a POSIX `sh` nowadays, and I didn't want to go through the trouble of setting up exactly your docker environment. (Which you didn't even exactly specify. For all I know, you could be running an image with `dash`, in a `busybox`, or whatever.) So that was a reasonable choice. Sorry it doesn't work for you. Let's wait for someone else to answer.

Comment: Oh you are right about dash, did not know it is there in busybox, sorry about that, but unfortunately it gives me the same results: error correct, but again in log ```out0 out1 out2 error0 error1 error2```

Comment: Well just tried on alpine docker instead, but dash is not there just checked ...

`# dash   sh: dash: not found`

Comment: @Cyborg-X1: busybox uses `ash`, as far as I can tell, but they're close. It doesn't work perfectly on my system, either, but it's at least close. I'm afraid that's all I can do at the moment. Let's wait for further answers. (The question doesn't have that many views yet.)

Comment: Hmm just thinking, could we instead of separating them just mark the errors somehow? then another tool (groovy script in jenkins for example) can separate them later. Example like putting sterr and stderr in xml tags like ```<stderr><![CDATA[error0]]></stderr>``` for each line